# TypeError "int" in Python

Tags: python, int

```
randsemiconclusion = [3234234, 234234, 23432]
wordstring = "                                                  "
liststr = list(wordstring)
for i in range(0, len(randsemiconclusion)):
    aw = randsemiconclusion[i]
    for j in range(0, 6):
        aac = int(i*7 + j+1)
        liststr[aac] = aw[j]
        wordstring = ''.join(liststr)
print("Wordstring -->  ", wordstring, "  <--")
```

Traceback:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> `liststr[aac] = aw[j]`
>
> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

(This is just an extractor the real code)

I am not sure as to why do I get the `TypeError`

This program is supposed to extract the numbers in the list and place them together in one string like so:

> list[12, 23, 32]
>
> to:
>
> 122332

Comment: *Where* does it give you that error?

Comment: If I'd  had to guess, I'd say `aw` is a `int` from the container `randsemiconclusion`. Provide the full traceback, as @DanielRoseman asked.

Comment: Presumably, `randsemiconclusion` is a list of `int` values, which would make `aw` an `int`.

Comment: what is `type(randsemiconclusion)` and `type(aw)`? If it's type `int`, there is your error.

Comment: It doesn't. It gives you `NameError: name 'randsemiconclusion' is not defined`.

Comment: no, it was defined earlier

Comment: Congratulations, your updated code **doesn't raise any error**.

Comment: please share some kind of input to this code and the expected output. It'll be a lot more easier for us to help you quickly. Instead of we assuming the contents of a list and their types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite the function like below:

```
def concatenate_list_data(list):
    result= ''
    for element in list:
        result += str(element)
    return result

my_result = concatenate_list_data([1, 5, 12, 2])   # leads to 15122
```

---

Another approach to the same can be using a list comprehension:

```
to_join = [1, 5, 12, 2]
output = ''.join([str(i) for i in to_join])
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for